# R: How can I prevent (or at least anticipate) name conflicts between code inside of base R functions and functions from later-installed packages?

Tags: r, namespaces, package, tidyverse, name-collision

I have a package (`tidyverse`) loaded that renames a base R function (`filter`).

I am running a base R function (`arima.sim`) that calls the `filter` function and returns an error from `dplyr::filter.ts`.

I can copy the code from `arima.sim` and create `arima.sim2`, replacing `filter` with `stats::filter`, which solves the problem. But:

1. The `dplyr` function `dplyr::filter.ts` helpfully reads:

   dplyr::filter.ts
   function (.data, ...) 
   {
       bad_args(".data", "must be a data source, not a ts object, do you want `stats::filter()`?")
   }

Is there anything that should have alerted me to this conflict besides the warnings when loading `tidyverse`? Because when I got those warnings, I had no idea I would be running `filter`, having not, at that time, read the code of `stats::arima.sim`.

2. Why didn't `stats::arima.sim` find `filter` in the `stats namespace` before looking in the `dplyr namespace`? Aren't package namespaces supposed to prevent this sort of thing?
3. Short of the re-creation of base R functions using `::` as described above, is there anything I can or should be doing to make sure that base R functions can find the other base R functions used in their definitions, rather than using same-named functions from later-installed packages?

Comment: So maybe something more involved is going on here because when I load dplyr and then run the examples from `?arima.sim` they seem to run fine, and find and call the correct filter function. So I sort of wonder if there isn't something else you've done to your workspace that's influencing things?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the new [conflicted](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/06/conflicted/) package. It is designed to avoid such problems by forcing the user to be explicit in case there is any ambiguity. Not sure if it will help in your exact case, I couldn't reproduce the behavior you described.